# Google Sheets iOS - Map documentation to SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets-api

It is extremely difficult to map the Google Sheets V4 documentation to the SDK methods. For example:

To append a row to a Spreadsheet, the [documentation states](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request) that there is a Request Resource, e.g.

```
"appendCells": {
    object(AppendCellsRequest)
  },
```

where AppendCellsRequest is

```
{
  "sheetId": number,
  "rows": [
    {
      object(RowData)
    }
  ],
  "fields": string,
}
```

However if I use the SDK as follows:

```
    let range = "Sheet1"
    let url = String(format:"%@/%@/values/%@", baseUrl, spreadsheetId, range)
    let params = ["valueInputOption":"RAW"]
    let fullUrl = GTLUtilities.URLWithString(url, queryParameters: params)

    let body = GTLObject()

    body.JSON = [ "appendCells" : [
                        "sheetId" : 0,
                        "rows"    : [[value, value, value, value]],
                        "fields"  : "*"
                     ]]

    driveService.fetchObjectByUpdatingObject(body, forURL: fullUrl, completionHandler: {
            (ticket:GTLServiceTicket!, object:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) in

    })
```

This fails with an error:

```
"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "append_cells" at 'data': Cannot find field."
```

Comment: Found a similar issue in this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/my-business-api/TUZGZiRIb3U/8EthBEQ5AgAJ). It suggested to make sure that the syntax of the [JSON representation](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v2/accounts.locations/patch#request-body) contained in your request body data is correct and that the field values you provide in your [PATCH request](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v2/accounts.locations/patch) for updating a location is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling the wrong URL.  Your URL is constructed as:

`let url = String(format:"%@/%@/values/%@", baseUrl, spreadsheetId, range)`

That will result in:

`http://sheets.googleapis.com/spreadsheets/{spreadsheet_id}/values/{range}`

... but you are trying to use the AppendCellsRequest object, which isn't supported by the values collection. Each Request object in your link is describing an object that belongs in the [request body](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate#request-body) of a batchUpdate call.  For more information, see the [Updating Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/batchupdate#example) guide.